# xcode prompt file is locked for editing doesn't remember Unlock choice after choosing "Do not show this message again"

Tags: xcode, perforce, xcode4.3

If I start typing in a readonly file in Xcode for the first time, I get prompted with a dialog that basically says the file is locked for editing, and asks me if I want to unlock it.

If I choose Unlock, I can continue editing the file.  At one point, I got annoyed at this (as I will always want it to unlock), and so I clicked "Do not show this message again", with the expectation that it would remember my choice.

However, while I no longer get prompted, it also does not unlock the files anymore - it seems the default without being prompted is always "Don't Unlock".

**Is there a way to automatically choose "Unlock" without being prompted every time?**

(Bit of background - I'm using Perforce for source control, and have an Xcode Behavior script set up to check out files when they are unlocked based on http://kb.perforce.com/article/1735/automatically-checking-out-files-for-edit-in-xcode-43, since Xcode no longer integrates nicely with Perforce)

Comment: to whoever downvoted this - is there anything unclear about this question I can improve? Although the end result is "no you can't do that", it still seems like a clear & valid question about a usability issue in xcode that people may run into...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to this is "No".

The behavior (and wording used in the dialog) is not to remember your selection, but to simply not prompt you again (and not make any changes).

Answer (score 0):

go to xcode-> preferences-> General -> Dialog warnings reset

Comment: This just makes it so the dialog pops up again, and does not answer the question of how to automatically 'unlock' without being prompted.

Comment: Xcode is brainy, it warns you so that you are aware of the happenings.I am thinking why do want to hide the dialog. If you really want to hide it. You can check the box, do not show the message again, before you unlock. And if you are editing a file that is network shared you will get this kind of dialogs. In which case you need to each file that you wanna edit needs to be unlocked.

Comment: The initial point of the problem was that I want xcode to always unlock, without prompting me.  If I choose 'do not show this message again' and then choose unlock, it does not remember I always want 'unlock' to be the action taken; instead, it just doesn't prompt and I cannot edit the file.

Comment: Well the answer is "NO". You really cant do it.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I needed the dialog box to come back. :)