# Perforce Issue: Opening a Storyboard controlled by Perforce Crashes Xcode

Tags: storyboard, xcode6, perforce, p4v

**The Issue** When you click on a Storyboard that in a project in Xcode that is managed by Perforce, Xcode crashes. The issue is related to Perforce. This is confirmed by "Checking out" the storyboard in Perforce before opening it. It opens just fine. 
If you don't check it out though... that's when a crash will occur. **How does one even go about fixing this?**

Here are the relevant log files I can post:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 6A1052d
>   ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6604/IDEKit/Editor/IDEEditorDocument.m:1816
>   Details:  Modifying document while unlocking is pending.
>   fileType:com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.Storyboard.XIB, change:2,
>   wasDocumentEdited:0, didHaveEditsSinceLastUserInitiatedSave:0 
>   _beginUnlockingBacktrace:  0  0x0000000106e03c37 -[IDEEditorDocument _unlockIfNeededCompletionBlock:] (in IDEKit)

Side note: This does not happen in Xcode 5 only 6... I have a feeling it is because Xcode 6 tried auto-updating the XML or something, while Perforce is saying "hey buddy, you need to unlock it first". That would explain why this only happens on Xcode 6 and not 5.

Comment: Looks like the issue might be Perforce related, can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440544/xcode-prompt-file-is-locked-for-editing-doesnt-remember-unlock-choice-after-cho

Comment: @IslamQ. Very interesting... I am using Perforce. I will look into this.. Thank you sir.

Comment: You're welcome!
Here's another link that might be useful: http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/3641-xcode-6-crash-when-checking-out-storyboard/

Comment: It sounds to me like the files need to be writable?  By default perforce sets files as readonly when not checked out.  So you simply need to checkout first.  Or you can set the file type to always writeable.

Answer (score 0):

Many IDE's don't like opening projects where the files are read only.  Some SCC systems keep everything writable (such as git) so that this isn't an issue, but others require that you tell the system what you are checking out (making writable) - perforce is one of these types.

Simply check out all the files in your project, it will make no difference to speed etc and will make sure you don't recieve any errors.